# animation locations with python

Tags: python, animation, physics

I try to design a physics animation with python / bpy.

The simulation as such is fine.

But I try to read the coordinates of falling objects while
running the simulation. For this purpose I use bpy.app.handlers,
which are called each time the frames change.

But if I try to access the locations of the falling objects,
it seems, that the you not change (although the objects
are obviously falling).

So I could guess, I would have to bake the simulation for
the locations are updated??

But more important: if not location is the property associated
with the falling cubes in the animation viewport,
which field could I use to access the simulated positions
WITHOUT baking the physics simulation before??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `matrix_world`, e.g.

```py
>>> C.object.matrix_world.translation
Vector((0.0, 0.0, -5.041865825653076))
>>> C.scene.frame_set(C.scene.frame_current + 1)
>>> C.object.matrix_world.translation
Vector((0.0, 0.0, -5.451406955718994))
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Works fine!